# How can I optimize the timing of this CountingSort algorithm in Scala

Tags: scala, median, counting-sort

I would like to ask you for help to identify which part of my code is not efficient. I am comparing the *QuickSort* algorithm with the *CountingSort* algorithm, assuming that the number of elements in an `Array[Byte]` is less than 16.

However, the *CountingSort* time is much higher than the *QuickSort* time, in all the tests I had performed sequentially. Then, I wanted to test this code in *Spark* to compute the *Median Filter*, but the results of the distributed execution times are consistent with the sequential execution times. What I mean is that *QuickSort* is always faster than *CountingSort*, even for smaller arrays.

Evidently something in my code is hanging the final processing.

This is the code:

```
def Histogram(Input: Array[Byte]) : Array[Int] = {
  val result = Array.ofDim[Int](256)
  val range = Input.distinct.map(x => x & 0xFF)
  val mx = Input.map(x => x & 0xFF).max
  for (h <- range)
    result(h) = Input.count(x => (x & 0xFF) == h)
  result.slice(0, mx + 1)
}

def CummulativeSum(Input: Array[Int]): Array[Long] = Input.map(x => x.toLong).scanLeft(0.toLong)(_ + _).drop(1)

def CountingSort(Input: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = {
  val hist = Histogram(Input)
  val cum = CummulativeSum(hist)
  val Output = Array.fill[Byte](Input.length)(0)
  for (i <- Input.indices) {
    Output(cum(Input(i) & 0xFF).toInt - 1) = Input(i)
    cum(Input(i) & 0xFF) -= 1
  }
  Output
}
```

Comment: The **time complexity** of counting sort is `O(n+k)`. If `k` is significantly greater than `n` (given that your n is *just* 16), using counting sort might not be the best choice in the first place (and maybe that's why quick-sort outperforms it?)

Comment: Let me see if I understood. Are you telling me that `n = 16` is great? I thought that `n = 1,000,000` was great.

Comment: **@Vitrion** sorry for the confusion. `O(n + k)` gives the impression of *Linear Time performance*, but that's true only when **`k` is much less than `n`**; because otherwise it approximates to `O(k)` which maybe much worse than our `O(n)` expectation. In this case n is only 16, so if k is (say) 10000, then we'll be looking at **O(10000x)** and **not O(16x)** type of performance

Answer (score 2):

You *can* build your histogram without traversing the input quite so many times.

```
def histogram(input :Array[Byte]) :Array[Int] = {
  val inputMap :Map[Int,Array[Byte]] = input.groupBy(_ & 0xFF)
                                            .withDefaultValue(Array())
  Array.tabulate(inputMap.keys.max+1)(inputMap(_).length)
}
```

I'm not sure if this is much faster, but it is certainly more concise.

```
def countingSort(input :Array[Byte]) :Array[Byte] =
  histogram(input).zipWithIndex.flatMap{case (v,x) => Seq.fill(v)(x.toByte)}
```

My tests show it produces the same results but there could be edge conditions that I've missed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to tell you that I already tested your code. Unfortunately, although your code is more concise, the timing performance is worse